# ipmitool : get user password

Tags: php, linux, ipmitool

How is it possible to get the password of a specific user in IMPItool (ex : id = 5) when I have the root access ?

when I try to get all users :

```
ipmitool -I lanplus -H <IPADDR> -U root -P changeme user list

ID  Name    Callin  Link Auth  IPMI Msg   Channel Priv Limit

1   false   false      true       NO ACCESS

2   root    false   false      true       ADMINISTRATOR

....

5   user    true    true       true       Operator
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impossible to get the password of specific user in IPMITool.

Answer (score 1):

The following is useful to check a password which you expect to be set on the system:

```
ipmitool user test <<USERID>> 20 <<EXPECTED PASSWORD>>
```

20 is the password size which can be a value of 16 or 20 depending on the length of the password.

This can be used for automation with idempotency to check before resetting.

Comment: `<<USERID>>` is the numerical ID of the user, not the user name.  To get the list of users with the IDs, use `ipmitool user list 1` where `1` is the id of the host (which will usually be 1).